# Selenium-Webdriver in Ruby with minitest. How to run specific test case inside a file

Tags: ruby, webdriver, minitest

Im transitioning from Rspec to minitest to test the later comparing speed and paralellism, maintenance, etc.

In Rspec, I can run my test cases with the command:

```
rspec path/to/test/suite.rb -e 'Should test this case'
```

'Should test this case' is this line inside the suite.rb file:

```
it 'Should test this case' do
    ...
end
```

But I can't seem to find any way to do this in minitest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not only that you can run individual tests, but you can also use Regex expressions

```
$ ruby path/to/test/suite.rb --name /Should test this case/
```